# How to execute an activity with a button inside another?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How do I execute one activity inside another, without going to it?
I mean, I have my **MainActivity** where I get some int arrays from **ReadFromAssetActivity** with intent. But to get these int arrays I need to execute **ReadFromAssetActivity** in first place and then go to **MainActivity** and execute it. 
What I want is to press a button in **MainActivity** that executes **ReadFromAssetActivity** without the need to go to that activity.

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to the button btn_chart
        Button btnChart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chart);

        // Defining click event listener for the button btn_chart
        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Draw the Chart
                openChart();
            }
        };

        // Setting event click listener for the button btn_chart of the SensorGraph layout
        btnChart.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }

    private void openChart() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        int[] force_l = intent.getIntArrayExtra("force_l");
        int[] force_r = intent.getIntArrayExtra("force_r");
        int[] x = new int[force_l.length];
(...)
```

**ReadFromAssetActivity**:

```
public class ReadFromAssetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button read_Button;
    int[] force_l = null;
    int[] force_r = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_from_asset);

        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        read_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ReadFromAssetActivity_start_reading_button);
        read_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ReadFromAsset().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ReadFromAsset extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("test.txt")));
                String mLine = null;
                int count = 0;
                while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] integer_Strings = mLine.split(" ");
                    //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(integer_Strings));
                    if (count == 0) {
                        force_l = new int[integer_Strings.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < integer_Strings.length; i++) {
                             force_l[i] = Integer.parseInt(integer_Strings[i]);
                        }
                        count++;
                    } else if (count == 1) {
                        force_r = new int[integer_Strings.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < integer_Strings.length; i++) {
                            force_r[i] = Integer.parseInt(integer_Strings[i]);
                        }
                     }

                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(ReadFromAssetActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("force_l", force_l);
                intent.putExtra("force_r", force_r);
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: then why you don't place your required code to `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 2):

What you intent on achieving is hardly a pure Android way to do things. You do not need separate 'ReadFromAssetActivity' or any other Activity to run your AsyncTask. The best idea would be to put your ReadFromAsset inside your MainActivity and call from your openChart method. Get your int arrays from AsyncTask in a callback interface.

If your task is actually way more complicated than you are showing to us in this snippet, please, consider the possibility of using an IntentService for that.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `ReadFromAsset` task a separate class (not an inner class of the activity) and have it store the arrays as its "result". Also give the task a way to remember a "listener" so that the `.onPostExecute()` can send those arrays back to the listener (in this case, your main activity). <s>I would type out a general example but I'm on mobile and there are lots of examples in the wild already.</s> **EDIT:** An example:

```java
/*
 * This consumer could be anything -- an activity, a service, a data
 * object, whatever. All it needs to do is implement the task's
 * listener interface.
 */
public class Example
implements MyTask.Listener
{
    // other code

    public void doThings()
    {
        (new MyTask()).setListener(this)
            .setInputFile( "flargle.txt" )
            .execute()
            ;
    }

    /** Specified by MyTask.Listener, called by MyTask#onPostExecute() */
    public void onMyTaskComplete( MyTaskResult res )
    {
        // Do something with the result.
    }
}

public class MyTaskResult
{
    // Stores whatever complex data you want the task to create.
    // Necessary only if what you're creating is really complex.
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,MyTaskResult>
{
    public interface Listener
    {
        void onMyTaskComplete( MyTaskResult res ) ;
    }

    protected Listener m_lstn ;
    protected String m_sFilename ;

    public MyTask setListener( Listener lstn )
    {
        m_lstn = lstn ;
        return this ;
    }

    public MyTask setInputFile( String sFilename )
    {
        m_sFilename = sFilename ;
        return this ;
    }

    @Override
    public MyTaskResult doInBackground( Void... aNulls )
    {
        MyTaskResult res = new MyTaskResult() ;
        // Do stuff that produces a MyTaskResult.
        return res ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute( MyTaskResult res )
    {
        m_lstn.onMyTaskCompleted( res ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a public static method in your ReadFromAssetActivity. Now you can add there what you require. You can call that method and execute  from Main activity according to your requirement.